# ionic : console.log not showing in xcode with cordova 4.1.1

Tags: xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I use ionic and updated cordova to version 4.1.1 (from 3.9.2). Almost everything works fine but my console.log don't show up in xcode anymore.

Any Idea  ?

$ ionic info :

Cordova CLI: 6.2.0
Gulp version:  CLI version 1.2.1
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.1
Ionic Framework Version: 1.0.1
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.16
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.7.3
ios-deploy version: 1.8.2
ios-sim version: 4.1.1
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v0.12.7
Xcode version: Xcode 7.3.1 Build version 7D1014

Update : installed plugin

$ ionic plugin list :
cordova-plugin-compat 1.0.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.3 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 2.2.0 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.4.0 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 3.2.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.1.3 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.2 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 5.1.1 "SocialSharing"
phonegap-plugin-push 1.7.2 "PushPlugin"

Answer (score 7):

Try adding ***cordova-plugin-console***

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-console
```

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-console

Comment: Sorry I should have listed my plugin. The console plugin is installed of course and was working fine when I used cordova ios 3.9.2.

Comment: Try removing it and re-adding. `cordova plugin rm cordoba-plugin-console` `cordova plugin add cordoba-plugin-console`. Then build your project.

Comment: Any other alternative?, I have removed it and added it again, it still fails.